# Знаете ли методы по нахождению минимального и максимального по значению элемента в массиве.C++

Tags: c++, массивы

Подскажите, как найти min и max число в массиве с помощью метода. Спасибо

Comment: *Метод* - слишком широкое понятие. Что *вы* в него вкладываете в этом вопросе? Что именно вам нужно? Алгоритмы `min_element`, `max_element` и `minmax_element` стандартной библиотеки?

Comment: Знаю https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, например, так:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector <int> vec {1, 2, 5 ,14, 5, -1, -34};
  std::cout << "Min element = " << *(std::min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end())) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Max element = " << *(std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end())) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Функция std::min_element и std::max_element делает это. Очень важный нюанс - возвращаемый результат нужно разыменовать, так как возвращаемое значение этих функций итератор.